# Curl print time of every sse event?

Tags: curl, server-sent-events

When I run

```bash
curl --request POST --url http://some-example.com/stream   --header 'Content-Type: application/json'   --data '{
"text": "hello"
}'
```

shell prints:

```
data:{"id":"chatcmpl-75BRIh9KeZv274g1AtHNq5d5POzEJ","object":"chat.completion.chunk","created":1681469968,"model":"gpt-3.5-turbo-0301","choices":[{"delta":{"role":"assistant"},"index":0,"finish_reason":null}]}

data:{"id":"chatcmpl-75BRIh9KeZv274g1AtHNq5d5POzEJ","object":"chat.completion.chunk","created":1681469968,"model":"gpt-3.5-turbo-0301","choices":[{"delta":{"content":"hello"},"index":0,"finish_reason":null}]}

data:{"id":"chatcmpl-75BRIh9KeZv274g1AtHNq5d5POzEJ","object":"chat.completion.chunk","created":1681469968,"model":"gpt-3.5-turbo-0301","choices":[{"delta":{"content":"."},"index":0,"finish_reason":null}]}
```

I want curl print datetime before every event

```
2023-04-14 08:13:12.418 data:{"id":"chatcmpl-75BRIh9KeZv274g1AtHNq5d5POzEJ","object":"chat.completion.chunk","created":1681469968,"model":"gpt-3.5-turbo-0301","choices":[{"delta":{"role":"assistant"},"index":0,"finish_reason":null}]}

2023-04-14 08:13:12.528 data:{"id":"chatcmpl-75BRIh9KeZv274g1AtHNq5d5POzEJ","object":"chat.completion.chunk","created":1681469968,"model":"gpt-3.5-turbo-0301","choices":[{"delta":{"content":"hello"},"index":0,"finish_reason":null}]}

2023-04-14 08:13:12.568 data:{"id":"chatcmpl-75BRIh9KeZv274g1AtHNq5d5POzEJ","object":"chat.completion.chunk","created":1681469968,"model":"gpt-3.5-turbo-0301","choices":[{"delta":{"content":"."},"index":0,"finish_reason":null}]}
```

I tried -v --trace-time, that did not work.

Is this possible ?

Comment: Where does that time come from?

Comment: The time I (the client/curl) receive this event